# Twitter Bootstrap Button Horizontal Middle Align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a little issue **centering horizontall**y my submit button.

```
<div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info'), 'submitTheThing') }}
   </div>
</div>
```

I also tried col-sm-offset-1 class property, but the button is not horizontally aligning middle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **col-sm-12** and **text-center** class properties gave me the answer. Thank you @Isuru Madusanka for leading me to the answer.

Here it is :

```
<body>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use text-align it will working fine

```
<body>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the first time i'm using jsfiddle, if i'm doing it right, it is here : http://jsfiddle.net/o1b89jfc/

Comment: <body>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: I have the answer try to use it

Comment: Thank you for giving me ideas. What i exactly wanted is here : http://jsfiddle.net/o1b89jfc/2/